# Hidden table in Docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

So, im seraching to how to hide the table when i create the document

Sometimes, the table is too big , and it would be good, if it will be print not at all

It is possible to hide table when i open document

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNei1.png)

And hiddeeen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlqLQ.png)

So, i need to make a table by default hidden when it just created

I was searching in documentation, but didnt find any solvation

Thanks for anybody who will help for this problem!! !

Comment: Make such a word document, if that is possible (tree view? collapse/expand). Then explore that document with Docx4j or rename the .docx to .zip and explore the content.xml.

Comment: You can try using outline level to do this.  For example, put the table under a heading which you can collapse/expand; see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/collapse-or-expand-parts-of-a-document-701786e0-95e2-40bf-bfe5-f0233cd3520c

Comment: @JasonPlutext Thanks about hyperlink, but that is an explanation of usage of it by interface

Comment: @JoopEggen what do you mean about "explore the content.xml" ?
If you tell, that there is some variants for inserting some tags to result xml text, so can you show me please this tags and places to put them

Comment: Actually, i found result

https://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-the-2012-extensions-t1942.html#p6694

Thanks @JasonPlutext for word "collapsed" that help me to fond this method!